# Crystal Reports Error: The Maximum Report Processing Jobs Limit

Tags: crystal-reports

On my web server, which is running Crystal Reports 2008 SP2 I've been getting the error "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached."

Having researched the topic online i came across a fix in which if you alter a registry value, specifically HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer\PrintJobLimit to "-1" you turn off the job limit.

I have altered that value but am still receiving the error. Shouldn't the -1 have stopped this?

If you have had any experience with this error, I would be very appreciative to hear how you solved it.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for Crystal Reports 13

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice Thread about that issue:
[MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/208525b2-94cd-4af6-9c5a-015e243b3092/)

Turning it off via using "-1" seems to be not an nice solution, it can cause site effects.
Try to raise the limit carefully and debug why the ranged is achieved. Optimise it!

Comment: Thx. I need some help with correctly closing and disposing it seems.

Comment: @Micah I read here http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crsdk_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crconsdkfundamentalsscalabilityclosemethod.htm that the right time to call the Close() method is during the Page_Unload event.