# The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report and I receive error :

```
The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached
```

I've searched stackoverflow and found 2 topic:

1. [Crystal Reports Error: The Maximum Report Processing Jobs Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578638/crystal-reports-error-the-maximum-report-processing-jobs-limit)
2. [Crystal Reports Exception: The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579914/crystal-reports-exception-the-maximum-report-processing-jobs-limit-configured-b)

But when i do as topic 1, change PrintJobLimit =-1, the error still happen.

When i do as topic 2, I haven't test yet because my report need navigate between pages. To navigate, I have to save report in session :

```
    ReportDocument reportDocument = null;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && Session["reportDocument"] != null)
        {
            reportDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["reportDocument"];
            crvReport.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        Session["reportDocument"] = reportDocument;
        crvReport.ReportSource = reportDocument;

        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/files/Users.rpt"));
        reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("******", "******", "*.*.*.*", "*****");
        reportDocument.VerifyDatabase();

        crvReport.DataBind();
    }
```

So I cannot dispose reportDocument in unload because Session["reportDocument"] change to null

```
    protected void crvReport_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (reportDocument != null)
        {
            reportDocument.Close();
            reportDocument.Dispose();
            reportDocument = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

So, how can I do navigating between pages in report, but I doesnot receive the error ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I found this link [Pdf file](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f053713e-3e3d-2c10-2a81-f79259e54023?QuickLink=support&overridelayout=true&43705587209382)

So, I don't close and dispose document in crvReport_Unload, but i close and dispose it when i redirect to another page.

```
//OnRedirect
ReportDocument reportDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["reportDocument"];
reportDocument.Close();
reportDocument.Dispose();
reportDocument = null;
GC.Collect();
```

And the error still happends but less offen.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in Crystal report version 11.5. After a lot of search I found different solutions like **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer** that says increase you print job limit etc but none of them worked for me. Then I just disposed off my `reportDocument with clone` and that worked like a charm. In my case after printing/generation report I did this

```
reportDocument.Close(); 
reportDocument.Clone(); 
reportDocument.Dispose(); 
reportDocument = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Morning, Have you tried anything from here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/208525b2-94cd-4af6-9c5a-015e243b3092/

Answer (score 0):

There is No permanent solution. 
After changing Registry and Code, problem arise within few hours.
Suggesting to change RDL or RDLC